# How to use class fields inside new statement using initializer syntax

Tags: c#

I have a class that I would like to instantiate. It contains two fields, one is a String, and the other is a Action.

Within the action statement, I would like to use the string field in my class. However, I do not know how to directly call it while instantiating. Is there any way, or will I have to create a field to contain the instantiated class, and then call text?

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public string text;
    public Action action;
    // on class instantiate -> action.Invoke();
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new ExampleClass
        {
            text = "Hello",
            action = () => { 
                 /* use the text element we specified to do something -> 
                    e.g Console.WriteLine(text); */ },
        };
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Trying to just use `text` field (like `action => ()=> {Console.WriteLine(text);}`) results in error:

> CS0103  The name 'text' does not exist in the current context

Comment: if you don't put in a variable then it is lost in memory and we don't have handle to that memory location

Comment: Side note: "on class instantiate -> action.Invoke()" - you do know that initializer syntax equivalent to setting properties *after* call to constructor, don't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The problem is, this is effectively a closure. You don't have access to the `this` of the instance you're creating in this manner so you need to "close" over it.

The `this` you have access to is actually the class which you're writing the code in. In this case, you don't have one because you're in a static function anyway.

```
using System;

public class ExampleClass
{
    public string text;
    public Action action;
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var instance = new ExampleClass
        {
            text = "Hello"
        };
        instance.action = () => Console.WriteLine(instance.text);
        instance.action();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am aware that this is one solution. I was hoping there was another way.

Comment: Nope, and I added more details explaining why.